# Python - How do I start an iteration from the n^th item of an iterable, and finish it on the n-1^th one?

Tags: python, list, loops

Say I have a list like `a = ["dog", "cat", "house", "mouse", "goose"]`. If I want to start a for loop at `a[3]` and end it at `a[2]`, how can I do that? `a[3:2]` of course returns an empty list, so I can't iterate on that. Is there a more pythonic way to do that than iterating over`a[3:]+a[:3]`?

To be clear, what I want is to have a for loop that starts at `a[n]`, then goes to `a[n+1]`, `a[n+2]` etc until the end of the list; then, when the last element of the list is reached, the loop continues from `a[0]` and goes on until `a[n-1]` (the same thing that I obtain with `a[3:]+a[:3]`).

Comment: Yes. You can iterate in reverse. Look up ::-1.

Comment: It sounds like `a[n:] + a[:n]` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
a = ["dog", "cat", "house", "mouse", "goose"]

print(a[3:2:-1])
```

And the output will be:

```
['mouse']
```

Obviously if you want to include the index `2` you have to write `a[3:1:-1]` (the final index it's not included as always)

---

**UPDATE:** after you have updated the request, this should be what you want

```
a = ["dog", "cat", "house", "mouse", "goose"]

print(a[3:] + a[:3])
```

The output will be:

```
['mouse', 'goose', 'dog', 'cat', 'house']
```

Answer (score 0):

When you slice a list like that (using a[3:-1]), the last item is non-inclusive.
Therefore, if you elements want up to **but not including the last element**, then -1 should work for you.
if you want up to but not including the last 2 elements, then -2 would work here.

e.g, for:

```
a = ["dog", "cat", "house", "mouse", "goose"]
a[3:-1]
```

output will be: ["mouse"].

Remember that the index of the list starts at 0.
so your list has elements with index from 0 to 4.
Printing from the 3rd till the penultimate elements is simply printing the 3rd element as it is the penultimate element too.

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for (see last paragraph).